# Difference between using "def" to update a var and "alter-var-root"

Tags: clojure

What's the difference between using "def" to update a var and using "alter-var-root"?
e.g.

```
(def x 3)
(def x (inc x))
```

vs

```
(def x 3)
(alter-var-root #'x inc)
```

Comment: Both answers were very enlightening, thank you! I wish I could accept both of them.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I find alter-var-root very rarely comes up in idiomatic Clojure code; not that there is anything wrong with it, it's just intended for corner cases. If you find yourself using it to build loops and such it's a sign something needs a different approach. I mostly see it in initialization routines for setting access credentials or loggers and such.

`alter-var-root` uses a function to mechanically change the value of a var while `def` just sets it to a new value. In your example they are equivalent.

```
hello.exp> (def foo 4)
#'hello.exp/foo
hello.exp> (alter-var-root #'foo inc)
5
hello.exp> foo
5
```

`alter-var-root` is also unwilling to create a new var:

```
hello.exp> (alter-var-root #'foo1 inc) 
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve var: foo1 in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1)
```

`alter-var-root` can work on other namespaces as well:

```
hello.exp> (in-ns 'user)
#<Namespace user> 
user> (alter-var-root #'hello.exp/foo inc) 
 6
user> (def hello.exp/foo 4)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create defs outside of current ns, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1)
user>
```

This last use case is the only one I have ever needed in practice. For instance forcing `clojure.logging` to use the correct slf4j logger as an example from the Pallet project:

```
(defn force-slf4j
  "The repl task brings in commons-logging, which messes up our logging
   configuration. This is an attempt to restore sanity."
   []
  (binding [*ns* (the-ns 'clojure.tools.logging.slf4j)]
    (alter-var-root
     #'clojure.tools.logging/*logger-factory*
     (constantly (clojure.tools.logging.slf4j/load-factory)))))
```

Which is just using `alter-var-root` to reset a var in another namespace regardless of its content on initialization. I suppose it's a bit of a hack ...

Comment: But defining a var more than once is considered bad style because `def` always define top level vars. If you want to change the binding of some var the right thing to do is use `alter-var-root`.

Comment: As a newbie, I feel like this answer explains *when you can use* `alter-var-root` but not **why** you'd use it.  What are some common use cases?

Comment: perhaps another use case is to set the value of an app handler, so when you're developing at the REPL you don't have to stop the app server when you change the handler that was passed to a create-server (I thought it would be easy to find a reference for this, but apologies as I'm coming up short atm).

Comment: @RodrigoTaboada: For already existing Var object calling `def` with its symbolic name **will not** create other object but will **update reference** in the existing one.

Comment: `alter-var-root` can be used to handle state initialization that occurs at runtime.  Common idiomatic usage examples can be found in Stuart Sierra's `component` library.  It is not a hack, though an atom could be used instead.  If the value is initialized at runtime once and only once, the semantic of using a var and `alter-var-root` might be clearer than using an atom.  But I imagine that `alter-var-root` would be slightly more challenging to grok for clojure beginners.

Answer (score 22):

`alter-var-root` provides the added value of being atomic with regards to the function application. Two (possibly concurrent) applications of `(alter-var-root #'foo inc)` guarantee that `foo` will increase by 2.

With `(def x (inc x))` there is no such guarantee. It might overwrite any changes done by other threads between reading the value of `x` and writing its updated value.

On the other hand, if you are using `alter-var-root` for its atomicity then perhaps atoms are better for your use case than vars.

Comment: There is no atomicity guarantee for either construct.

Comment: Or perhaps I'm thinking of with-redefs...got a link to the guarantee?

Comment: @amalloy `alter-var-root` delegates to `clojure.lang.Var.alterRoot` which is `synchronized`. `bindRoot` is also `synchronized`, but of course it takes the new root value as an argument, which therefore must be ready before it attempts to acquire the lock.

Comment: @amalloy: I remember the docstring on alter-var-root stating something about "atomically applying" the change. Will try to recheck when I get to a proper browser.

Comment: Here are the relevant fragments of the 1.5.1 source: [`clojure.core/alter-var-root`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.5.1/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4941), [`clojure.lang.Var.alterRoot`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.5.1/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Var.java#L335). Edit: the docstring does mention this guarantee too -- "Atomically alters..." -- as per Rafał's comment (since I'm on a proper browser right now ;-)).

Answer (score 15):

With `def`:

```
(def w (vector))        ; create Var named w and bind it to an empty vector
(dotimes [x 9]          ; repeat 9 times (keeping iteration number in x):
 (future                ;  execute in other thread:
  (def w                ;   replace root binding of w with
    (conj w             ;    a new vector with all elements from previous (w)
          x))))         ;     with added an element indicating current iteration (x) 

w                       ; get a value of Var's root binding (identified by symbol w)

; => [0 2 3 6 8 7 4 5]  ; 1 is missing !!!
                        ; second thread overlapped with another thread
                        ; during read-conjoin-update and the other thread "won"
```

With `alter-var-root`:

```
(def w (vector))        ; create Var named w and bind it to an empty vector
(dotimes [x 9]          ; repeat 9 times (keeping iteration number in x):
 (future                ;  execute in other thread:
  (alter-var-root #'w   ;   atomically alter root binding of w
   (fn [old]            ;    by applying the result of a function,
    (conj               ;     that returns a new vector
     old                ;      containing all elements from previous (w)
     x)))))             ;      with added an element indicating current iteration (x) 

w                       ; get a value of Var's root binding (identified by symbol w)

; => [1 2 4 5 3 0 7 8 6]
```