# Does the Clojure special form `def` always create a new Var?

Tags: clojure

I know that in Clojure, namespaces map symbols to Vars. So we can map the symbol `x` to a Var (here in the default namespace) like this:

```
user=> (def x 5)
#'user/x
user=> #'x
#'user/x
user=> (type #'x)
clojure.lang.Var    
user=> x
5
```

Now if I subsequently say this

```
user=> (def x 3)
#'user/x
```

Have I rebound the symbol `x` to a brand new Var or have I updated the value in the same Var I created above? How would I know?

I'm thinking it's the latter because I read the sentence "Only Java fields, Vars, Refs and Agents are mutable in Clojure." in the [Clojure Reference page on Vars](http://clojure.org/reference/vars) but I'm not sure that holds as a proof.

Comment: Your hunch seems confirmed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447621/difference-between-using-def-to-update-a-var-and-alter-var-root

Comment: Good find.... I was hoping there was something like a Python or Ruby `id`, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `def` does not always create a new `Var`. You can confirm this using `identical?`:

```
user=> (def x 5)
#'user/x
user=> (def v #'x)
#'user/v
user=> (def x 3)
#'user/x
user=> (identical? v #'x)
true
```

Answer (score 3):

Elogent's answer is excellent and accepted, but I just found another way to prove that a new var is not created, which might be of use:

```
user=> (def x 10)
#'user/x
user=> (let [y #'x] (println @y) (def x 7) (println @y))
10
7
nil
```

If `def` did create a new var, we would have seen 10 printed twice.